# ListView OnItemClickListener is not always firing

Tags: android, listview

It seems like my ListView OnItemClickListener does not always seem to be called.  The ListView uses embedded TextViews.

If you click at the top or bottom 3px of each item then the listener does fire.

If you click on the text of the TextView then the listener does not fire as though it is consuming/blocking the  click.

I have tried many combinations of adding `focusable="false"`, `clickable="false"` and `focusableInTouchMode="false"` to the TextView and adding `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` to the root view.

activity_local_explorer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
tools:context="my.package.FileBrowser">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/local_file_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:clickable="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/local_file_view_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class LocalExplorer extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_local_explorer);

    String[] values = { "Hello", "My", "Friend"};

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.local_file_view);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.activity_local_explorer, R.id.local_file_view_text, values));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            String selectedValue = getItemAtPosition(position);
            Snackbar.make(listView, selectedValue, 2).show();
        }    
    });
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been spending hours on this simple activity!

Comment: I do not see anything obviously wrong. Try removing `android:clickable` from your ListView. You want to allow the user to click on individual rows, not the entire view.

Comment: What is the purpose of the TextView?

Comment: I assume layout.xml is really activity_local_explorer.xml. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah that is correct name for the xml sorry I will edit /correct the post (I have also changed it to display simple strings for now). I was planning on using an icon in the row view (some kind of custom layout) so I just used a TextView for now to get it working with a custom view.  When I removed the `andoird:clickable` from ListView the behaviour did not seem to change.  The top/bottom 3 pixels of each row can clicked but the middle text part does not register

Answer (score 0):

First I'd like to thank those who tried to help me answer my question, your time was much appreciated.

OK I got this working at long last by slightly changing the approach.  I moved the TextView out of the `activity_local_explorer.xml` into its own xml layout file and used a different constructor when creating the adapter.

activity_local_explorer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
tools:context="my.package.FileBrowser">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/local_file_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

local_explorer_row.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Activity

```
public class LocalExplorer extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_local_explorer);

    String[] values = { "Hello", "My", "Friend"};

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.local_file_view);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.local_explorer_row, values));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

            String selectedValue = getItemAtPosition(position);
            Snackbar.make(listView, selectedValue, 2).show();
        }    
    });
}
```